# UEFI handler of key pressing

Tags: c, uefi

I'm trying to find something like a handler of key pressing in UEFI. I expect that it'll be the function that performs when I press any key.

I've found that there is RegistryKeyNotify() function in EfiSimpleTextInputExProtocol. But as I see it I should pass concrete KeyStroke as the second argument while I would want that this function triggers on any key.

I think that one way is to construct function above for each key personally. But of course, I don't like this idea.

Is there a way to solve my problem?

Comment: I am not able to post answer here. But you can check [gnu-efi](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnu-efi/) and [this example](https://github.com/hummelchen/uefilog).

Comment: Can you explain what you are wanting to actually do with this? Are you looking to do something for which EFI_SIMPLE_TEXT_INPUT_PROTOCOL.ReadKeyStroke() isn't enough?

Comment: @unixsmurf I think it is clear when OP says `I would want that this function triggers on any key`. Rather than waiting for a key, OP needs a event handler for every key press.

Comment: @Sandeep It looks like it could solve my problem. I'll try this. Thanks!

Comment: @unixsmurf Yes. I don't know the exact moment when user will press any key. So I want something that looks like asynchronous function which triggers at not determined time moment.